# How does Jboss Resteasy automatic decompression prevent zip bomb attack?

Tags: jboss, zip, gzip, resteasy

I'm using Jboss Resteasy to set up web service. Just find out Resteasy is automatically decompressing gzip message according to below:
https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/gzip.html

What if a client sends a zip bomb? Wondering how Resteasy handles this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flaw was identified and CVE was assigned: [CVE-2016-6346](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2016-6346).

The description states:

> In order to reduce the risk of being exploited by this vulnerability, the default setting for RESTeasy was changed so that it no longer decodes requests with gzip compression

The fix is included in RESTeasy 3.1 branch and in 3.0.20 (and newer).

So my suggestion is to use an up-to-date version of RESTeasy.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It makes sense.